# Swift JSON dates

Tags: json, swift

What would be most efficient way to handle and format different date strings returned from the same JSON object. The API I'm using returns either `2021-02-08T21:00-08:00` or  `2021-02-09T06:00+01:00` etc, based on location. The API also includes a timezone string which may be handy - `Europe/London`

Previous code before noticing the API includes different strings.

```swift
func timeFormat(date: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-ss:SSS"
    ///formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+ss:SSS"
    let formattedDate = formatter.date(from: date) ?? Date()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h a"
    return formatter.string(from: formattedDate)
}
```

**UPDATE**

As *@gcharita* and *@JoakimDanielson* pointed out my string was the same but I accidentally formatted it incorrectly. Now it's working fine. My mistake and take full credit for it.

```swift
func timeFormat(date: String) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"
    let formattedDate = formatter.date(from: date) ?? Date()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h a"
    return formatter.string(from: formattedDate)
}
```

Comment: I’ve already tried using ISO8601DateFormatter, that’s not the format returned by the API.

Comment: The main point of my linked question was to use Codable and decoder.dateDecodingStrategy but I guess that didn’t become very clear. Sorry. Also, I fail to see the difference between the two sample dates. I see different values but not different formats.

Comment: `-ss:SSS` that part is wrong, since I don't see what's is supposed to be matching the `ss` in the sample String. You didn't understood that `-08:00` mean minus 8h from GMT.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks for the clarification, that was the issue after all. I updated my original answer with what now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-08:00` and `+01:00` of the example dates are not seconds and milliseconds as you specify in your date format. (`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm-ss:SSS"` and `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm+ss:SSS"`) This is the ISO 8601 time zone format.

As @JoakimDanielson mentioned in the comments, both dates have the same format which apparently is: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it was indeed my time string that was formatted incorrectly. I used `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"` and it works just fine now. I attempted to use ISO8601DateFormatter() but needed strictly hours.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only have to deal with one date format (as previous posters mentioned) you should leave this to the `JSONDecoder` and simply define the `dateDecodingStrategy` like this:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZZZZZ"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
```

Now your `decoder` will happily convert all dates that match the given format. Much easier than dealing with all the messy formats yourself.